# Fetching images and setting them makes the app freeze using Combine SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Hello I'm currently having a problem with displaying images when they are fetched from url. So I currently fetch data from genius API and I get the information needed while also getting an image url, however when I set the data to a view then the app freeze for a few second and later it works fine.

I get my data by the following way:

```
class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<NetworkManager, Never>()
    var imageLoader = ImageLoader()

    var fetchedSongsResults = [SongCardViewModel]() {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    func fetchSongs(userSearched callback: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.genius.com/search?q=\(callback.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20"))") else { return }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.setValue("Bearer", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

      URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let songs = try! JSONDecoder().decode(feed.self, from: data)
            self.imageLoader.fetchSongImages(urlStrings: songs.response.hits.map({ $0.result.imageUrl }))
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if self.imageLoader.dataIsValid == true {
                    for song in songs.response.hits {

                        self.fetchedSongsResults.append(SongCardViewModel(Id: song.result.id, ImageURL: self.imageLoader.fetchedImage[0], LyricsUrl: song.result.lyricsUrl, Title: song.result.title, Lyrics_State: song.result.lyrics_state, Primary_Artist: song.result.primary_artist))
                    }
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

So, network manager is like my main class and as you can see in the function fetchSongs I call another class which is imageLoader which also is an fetches the images and appends to the array fetched image, I have hard coded the 0 index don't mind that. Here is the following code for imageLoader

```
class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dataIsValid = false
    var fetchedImage = [Data]()

    func fetchSongImages(urlStrings: [String]) {
        for urlString in urlStrings {
            guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dataIsValid = true
                    self.fetchedImage.append(data)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Just to be clear the data is displayed and however when I set the view and trigger the network manager with the callback I can see the data has been received but when I try to scroll down I can't until I wait a few seconds my theory is that the images are still being fetched from background and that is why the app freezes, I have tried to use the isDataValid boolean to determine also when the images are fetched but sadly it didn't work.

here is the code on how I show the data

```
@ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()

    var body: some View {
           ScrollView {
                    ForEach(self.networkManager.fetchedSongsResults, id: \.title) { song in
                        VStack {
                            NavigationLink(destination: LyricView(url: song.lyricsUrl)) {
                                SongCardView(isSearching: self.isSearching, imageData: song.imageUrl, title: song.title, artist: song.primary_artist.name)

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Here is my custom SongCardView

```
truct SongCardView: View {
    var isSearching: Bool
    var imageData: Data
    var title: String
    var artist: String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            CustomImageView(ImageData: imageData)
            HStack {
                Text(title)
                    .modifier(SongCardViewTextModifier())
                Text("-")
                    .modifier(SongCardViewTextModifier())
                Text(artist)
                    .modifier(SongCardViewTextModifier())

            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 240, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 30)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.8))
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

The thing that is most curious to me is that when I tried I remove self.isDataValid = true from dispatchQueue and have be outside of the for loop it didn't work instead my array fetched image became empty and I don't know why?. The main goal is that to stop make app freeze and my conclusion was that the images are the ones that makes things hard because they get fetched before the images. Thank you for helping

Here is SondCardViewModel:

```
class SongCardViewModel: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var imageUrl: Data
    var lyricsUrl: String
    var title: String
    var lyrics_state: String
    var primary_artist: artist

    init(Id:Int, ImageURL:Data, LyricsUrl:String, Title:String, Lyrics_State:String, Primary_Artist: artist) {
        id = Id
        imageUrl = ImageURL
        lyricsUrl = LyricsUrl
        title = Title
        lyrics_state = Lyrics_State
        primary_artist = Primary_Artist

    }

}
```

Also here is CustomImageView

```
import SwiftUI

func imageFromData(_ data:Data) -> UIImage {
    UIImage(data: data) ?? UIImage()
}

struct CustomImageView: View {
    var imageData: Data
    init(ImageData data:Data) {
        imageData = data
    }

    var body: some View {
        // checking for our fetched is not nil if nil then we just use an empty UIImage
        // if we have fetched our image then we set as our image
        Image(uiImage: imageFromData(imageData))
           .renderingMode(.original) 
           .resizable()
           .cornerRadius(30)
           .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/1.5, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/1.5)
    }
}
```

Comment: and your CustomImageView....? and SongCardViewModel?

Comment: @Chris so have now included CusomImageView and SongCardViewModel

Comment: now artist and lyricview missing....please give us reproducable runnable coding examples....

Comment: @Chris sorry I thought it would be too much code so that is why I didn't put all of it here as It would be very messy, however the project is actually published on GitHub and you can visit here with the following link https://github.com/Atheer2104/MusicX

Comment: @Chris figured the problem and the app freeze because of the navigation link if you take it out song card view from the navigation link and comment out the navigation link the app doesn't freeze at all, however I'm think if I can't use navigation link then I could just make the image clickable or add button that covers the entire area, perhaps a better solution

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this problem was that NavigationLink why actually the one that made the app freeze when removing it it worked as excepted